# Bootstrap dropdown only works in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Last night my app had a bootstrap drop down that worked in production and development. I added a bootstrap collapse for another section of the page and now my drop down only works in development, the collapse works fine in both. I understand that this is somehow Jquery related as I've seen a ton of other posts with a similar question. It has been very frustrating to test having to push to Heroku every time I try something new. During all of this I may have deleted a line from application.js because it seemed to have been working until put into production. I will look through my commits for what I had originally in the meantime.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recompiled the assets? Usually, when deploying changes, you will have to recompile js and css (minify/unify/gzip) in order for the production environment to catch the changes

This should be enough in most cases, running:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. So why is it that when you run the server locally the JS gets compiled without that command?

Comment: [Here] https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices) is a useful article. Basically, if compiled assets don't exist, they will be created on server start (production). So, you would get the same result of you manually delete the compiled assets folder and restart the server.